# Can I use mac's system sound for commercial product?

Tags: macos, audio, system

/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/system/

Can I use the sound files in the folder for commercial product?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a legal question, and should be asked at Apple. Any answer you receive here is someone else's interpretation, and if you get sued because they got it wrong it's your money that gets taken, not theirs. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Copying a sound file and shipping with your product — totally no, but loading it from that location and playing? That's an interesting question.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Ken White, the only way to get a definitive, authoritative answer is to contact Apple and ask them.

Comment: No matter what the answer is, it is dangerous because Apple can move them whenever they want. (They actually did. In Lion, they are in `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system`.)